# Why is the return function called return?

Tags: function, haskell, io, return

Why is the [return](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3areturn) function called return?

The description is:

> Inject a value into the monadic type.

The name not only doesn't make sense (to me), it is confusing for people coming from an imperative language where `return` is a language keyword that returns from the function.

Comment: I personally consider it meaningless, `pure` is a better choice from `Applicative`.  Since every `Monad` is an `Applicative` with (hopefully) `pure = return`, it wouldn't be difficult to leave `return` out of the definition of `Monad` entirely with the upcoming `Functor -> Applicative -> Monad` restructuring.

Comment: Well, it does look like the imperative control flow keyword in code like `liftM f x = do { x' <- x; return (f x) }`

Comment: Furthermore, the description "Inject a value into the monadic type" is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: It's an arbitrary choice, it's best to just assume your intuition for the definition of the English word "return" won't help you understand the monad ``return`` operation at all.

Comment: Blame Phil Wadler. :)

Comment: @StephenDiehl: but is there any English word that helps in understanding "monadic injection"? `pure` doesn't, though it gives perhaps less of _wrong_ connotations. `inject` itself might be a candidate, but this, too, doesn't explain what's going on. You don't get around learning monads properly at some point, but we can't expect Haskell beginners to do that right at away. Up until that point, the main question is: is it more helpful that there's a `return` "keyword" which kinda sorta looks like `return` in procedural languages, or is it more confusing that it does not really behave the same?

Comment: There are monads for which `return` is not an injection.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't think I have an objective opinion at this point, but I do think ``return`` is so overloaded in programming that it causes needless frustration for beginners. If it were up to me it would just be ``mu``, ``eta``, and ``(>>=)`` to just leave it as the abstract structure like the underlying monad concept is.

Comment: I don't see why people think this an opinion-based question.  It's a valid question.

Comment: @pigworker: However those monads are all isomorphic to `Const`, aren't they?

Comment: `if condition then putStrLn "..." else return ()` is a good example of why it's not always intuitive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why is it called that? Because it's *usually* the very last function in a monadic block of code. Usually the only good reason to use `return` is to set the final return value from your monadic action.

I too think that this is a very, very poor name choice. But it's not like we can fix it now...

Comment: Actually, _now_ we can. Let’s just stop using `return` and always use `pure` instead!

Answer (score 10):

It's purely historical. Most Haskell developers agree it's a bad name. It breaks the principle of least surprise. Quite a few of the older library functions are a bit wonky (the plethora of error handling schemes and a few other typeclass element names come to mind).

As @bheklilr says, there is a restructuring underway which should help:

- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal

These are good places to start if you are interested in the meta of Haskell:

- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Future_of_Haskell
- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category:History

Answer (score -3):

The answer is because it returns something. It you use in PHP for example -  echo something in it, it returns that text or data. But functions primary power is not in echoing data directly. Their power is in storing data and returning variable/array or similar where are data is stored.

You can also return true or false based on data/calculation. In classes, functions are named methods and do the same thing - return something. In java return can be void (echoed data), or strict data type (boolean for example, or String, Array, etc).

After return function data is not being returned.

Comment: This answer isn't technically wrong, but partly because it's [too vague to actually make any statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) — It's not even clear you're actually talking about the [`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) method in Haskell. You're aware that this is something “almost, but not quite” completely different from the `return` keyword in procedural/OO languages, right? — Regarding your first sentence: _every [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29)_ returns something in Haskell.